# How to deploy a VM Scale set in exisiting vnet?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

How can I deploy a VM scale set generalized image into an existing vnet?

Are there some powershell commands to do this?

How could I go about this?

Comment: I tried to improve the wording of your question a bit, please review my changes and see if you find them helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scale set with `New-AzureRmVmss` command that uses the `-ImageName` parameter. I run the following Powershell Scripts successfully. The existing virtual network and existing Image are in the same resource group.

```
New-AzureRmVmss `
  -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
  -Location "EastUS" `
  -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet" `
  -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
  -SubnetName "mySubnet" `
  -PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIPAddress" `
  -LoadBalancerName "myLoadBalancer" `
  -UpgradePolicyMode "Automatic" `
  -ImageName "myImage"
```

Ref1: [Create a VMSS with New-AzureRmVmss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/new-azurermvmss?view=azurermps-6.8.1#description)